# Principal minors of a negative definite matrix

Tags: matrices

If matrix A is negative definite, then we know that all leading principal minors of even order are positive and all leading principal minors of odd order are negative. But does the same work for all principal minors and not only the leading ones?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the submatrix corresponding to any principal minor is itself a negative definite matrix.